# Validate ASP.net calendar control against current date

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, calendar

I'm using an ASP.net calendar control and need to validate that the chosen date is after the current date. So if the user tries to choose a date on the calendar that is before the current date, it will give an error.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you using the actual .net Calendar control or a textbox with a popup calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
if(calendercontroldate < DateTime.Now.Date)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Careful, how do you handle time zone differences? `DateTime.Now.Date` returns the server's local time, but what if the user is in a timezone such that their date is different to the server's?

Answer (score 1):

Calender control doesn't have a predefined validator. You have to use a CustomValidator for this purpose

Add a CustomValidator for your Calender Control and check the date OnServerValidate event of CustomValidator method

```
public void Custom_validaor_Validate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    if( calnderDate > DateTime.Now )
    {
        //Code here
    }
}
```

On your Submit button click check the page is validated or not by saying

```
public void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        // the button click event executes even if the page isn't
        // valid, so you have to wrap your save event
        // in this kind of if block to avoid saving bad data to
        // to the database.
    }
}
```